# Need help understanding flow of react redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux

Took course on Udemy "Modern React and Redux" , Still not very clear about how data flows...
Please suggest How to Learn Reactjs and Redux,
What sources are best for basics?
How to start programming in reactjs?

Comment: I recommend having a solid grounding in React before approaching Redux. This will help you understand state better. Redux is better for larger applications. You can learn some React basics at codeacademy.com. For redux, a series that helped me understand the basics better is the learncode.academy youtube series at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1w-oQ-i1XB8

Comment: Thanks Dream_Cap

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best source material concerning Redux and how to use it with React are these courses created by Dan Abramov (the creator of Redux).

https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux

The first course explains you what Redux is about, how it is made and how to use it.

The second course is more pratical, it shows you how to use it in a real application using React.

I personnally have learned how to use React and Redux using these two courses only.

Comment: Hey Massinissa Mokhtari, Thanks and I went through those courses...<br/> It helped a lot